# Pycharm 2023.2 (CE) does not recognize packages installed with pip install -e when using a python virtualenv

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

- In an Linux ubuntu shell
- In a python 3.9 **virtualenv** installed "my_package" with `pip install -e <path_to_my_package>`
- In a **module** in the pycharm editor: `import <my_package>`
- **PyCharm** throws an error for <my_package> `reference not found`

The same installation on Pycharm worked perfectly for months before it suddenly started throwing the error.

All these attempts **failed**.

- Restarting Pyhcarm, invalidating it's caches, repairing the IDE
- Delete and reload the package with `pip uninstall <my_package>` and `pip install -e <my_package>`
- Delete and reinstall it in the Pycharm Interpreter settings.

This **worked**  (but the package was not editable of course, so **useless** in this case):

- re-install the package in **non** editable mode: `pip install -e <my_package>`
- No Pycharm error.

Comment: Have you checked the PyCharm project settings (in the 'File' menu) to see that the project is actually using the virtual environment you expect it to use?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-remote-interpreters

Comment: @Grismar Yes checkedit. File-->Project-->Python Interpreter--> shows :Python 3.0 (envPych)

Comment: @dawid.pawlowsk Thank you. Good link.  I did use that to set up the venv originally.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix !  **Deactivate and reactivate the Linux shell virtualenv**.

- To recap: Both Linux and Pycharm were running with the virtualenv "envPych" activated.
- in the linux shell: `deactivate`  # Deactivated the linux virtualenv
- Reactivate it: `source: <path_to_venv_directory>/bin/activate`
- restart Pycharm.